# How to retrieve choice column in sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365

I am creating a dropdown and want to fill it with choices with my choice column of SharePoint list.
Looking for solution in CSOM or JSOM.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try this using CSOM:

```
    function GetChoiceValues()
{

var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();


this.taskList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("CMA");
this.fields= this.taskList.get_fields();

var deptChoiceField = context.castTo(this.taskList.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Category"),SP.FieldChoice);
context.load(this.taskList);
context.load(this.fields);
context.load(deptChoiceField);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod),Function.createDelegate(this,this.onFailureMethod));

}
function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {
 alert("Error Occured: "+ args.get_message());
}

function onSuccessMethod(sender, args)
{
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var myChoicesfield = context.castTo(this.fields.getByInternalNameOrTitle("Category"),SP.FieldChoice);
var choices = myChoicesfield.get_choices();
for(i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
 {
   //divHtml+="<option value='"+choices[i]+"'>"+choices[i]+"</option>";
   console.log(choices[i]);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using rest API, just make a GET request to the following end-point:

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Choice Field Name'"
```

## Example using jQuery

```
$.ajax({
        url: "host url"+"_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Choice Field Name'",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d.results[0].Choices.results);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }

    });
```

Comment: Nice one. host url can be derived from _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl.